# How to let the minted NFT load instantly after being minted?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

I am creating a smart contract which allows users mint NFTs from my collection. But I found an issue that sometimes the metadata json won't load properly on trading platforms like Opensea or LooksRare when they finish minting, and they have to click the refresh metadata button manually in order to receive the attributes, name and image of the NFT. I wish my users can see those data instantly after the NFT is minted. The metadata json is confirmed to be available for the whole time before and after the minting.

I also noticed that some NFTs are loaded on LooksRare but not on Opensea initially, and some NFTs is only on Opensea but not on LooksRare. After refreshing metadata they are showing on both platform though. Would that be a platform based issue?

UPDATE: According to this website [https://medium.com/web-design-web-developer-magazine/quick-hack-to-refresh-opensea-metadata-on-many-nfts-quickly-6b8a2a52b080#:~:text=Normally%2C%20I%20tell%20people%3A%20Go,it%20takes%20a%20few%20tries](https://medium.com/web-design-web-developer-magazine/quick-hack-to-refresh-opensea-metadata-on-many-nfts-quickly-6b8a2a52b080#:%7E:text=Normally%2C%20I%20tell%20people%3A%20Go,it%20takes%20a%20few%20tries)). it seems there's no way to get around it and I would have to ask my clients to click refresh if they didn't see the image. Still, I wish there's a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what Opensea support told me, there's no solution for achieving this so far (because the IPFS might load slower than the platform's fetching mechanic) and we have to ask the users to refresh metadata manually if it is not loaded properly.